# In ASP.NET Core, how do I use a service that is setup in ConfigureServices() in Configure()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a service I wrote that helps with configuration.  The service is set up in the Startup class's ConfigureServices method as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();

    ...
}
```

I need to then get an instance of IMyService in the Startup class's Configure method.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you've already added your service with `AddScoped`, all you need to do is add another parameter to the `Configure` method with the correct type and the dependency injection system will take care of it for you:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, 
    IMyService myService)
{
    //Snip
}
```

Comment: I also figured out I can instantiate it with "var myservice = App.ApplicationServices.GetService<IMyService>();".  I think your answer is better though.  :)