# ASP.Net Core 5 ConfigureServices using reflection based on instance created by a service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a **.Net Core 5** API having 2 types of models:

- **Entities** (used by Entity Framework Core)
- **DTOs** (Data Transfer Objects for requests and responses, replacing "{Property}Id" properties from Entity with "{Property}Code" in DTO)

I have a service responsible of mapping Entities types to Dtos types added as singleton in **ConfigureServices**:

`services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEntityDtoMappingProvider), typeof(EntityDtoMappingProvider));`

The service **EntityDtoMappingProvider** has a method which returns the mapping between Entities and Dtos for an assembly through reflection described by this interface:

```
public interface IEntityDtoMappingProvider
{
    Dictionary<Type,Type> GetEntityDtoMapping(Assembly assembly);
}
```

I have an **AutoMapper Profile** requiring Entities and DTOs mapped, returned by the first service **IEntityDtoMappingProvider**:

```
public class EntitiesToDtosProfile : Profile
{
    public EntitiesToDtosProfile(Dictionary<Type,Type> mapping)
    {
        if (mapping == null || mapping.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( $"Empty mapping argument passed to {nameof(EntitiesToDtosProfile)} profile", nameof(mapping));
        }

        foreach(var item in mapping)
        {
            // Create AutoMapper mapping both ways based on those types
            CreateMap(item.Key, item.Value); // Entity-DTO
            CreateMap(item.Value, item.Key); // DTO-Entity
        }
    }
}
```

I need to create the AutoMapper profile in **Startup.cs** in **ConfigureServices** method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEntityDtoMappingProvider), typeof(EntityDtoMappingProvider));

    // Note: Using services.BuildServiceProvider() is a bad practice because an additional copy of singleton services being created
    using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
    {
        var mappingService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEntityDtoMappingProvider>();
        var mappings = mappingService.GetEntityDtoMapping(typeof(Workflow).Assembly);

        // Add AutoMapper IMapper to services
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new EntitiesToDtosProfile(mappings));
        });
        var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        
        // Here I should call other IServiceCollection extensions like:

        // Database-related services: GenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        services.AddDatabaseGenericRepositories<ApplicationDbContext>(mappings, Log.Logger);

        // Mapping-related services: MappingHelper<TEntity, TDto> : IMappingHelper<TEntity, TDto>
        services.AddMappingHelpers(mappings, Log.Logger);

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

As I was saying in the code, using **services.BuildServiceProvider()** is a bad practice because an additional copy of singleton services being created, creates a second container, which can create torn singletons and cause references to object graphs across multiple containers. [Microsoft .Net Core 5 documentation backing those statements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Please give an answer about how I should create the Entity-DTO mapping of type **Dictionary<Type,Type>** in **CreateServices** using **IEntityDtoMappingProvider** in order to build the AutoMapper profile **EntitiesToDtosProfile** and create other services through reflection without calling **services.BuildServiceProvider** taking into considerations the following:

- I have many services created through reflection using extension methods for IServiceCollection **requiring Entity-DTO mapping in ConfigureServices**
- I cannot use **IOptions** having a property of type **Dictionary<Type,Type>** because IOptions shouldn't be used in **ConfigureServices**: "An inconsistent options state may exist due to the ordering of service registrations." Source: [IOptions Microsoft Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- I looked through [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di-from-within-configureservices/32461714#32461714) [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288716/why-we-need-to-call-buildserviceprovider-to-get-dependencies-everytime) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774559/how-do-i-get-a-instance-of-a-service-in-asp-net-core-3-1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815092/in-asp-net-core-how-do-i-use-a-service-that-is-setup-in-configureservices-in) (some might be a little unrelated), but all solved their issues using **services.BuildServiceProvider()** or **IOptions** which is not ok.

Comment: If you are only registering `IEntityDtoMappingProvider` so that you use it to build your mapping component then maybe you shouldn't register it.

Comment: Good point, I only use it to create an AutoMapper profile (EntitiesToDtosProfile) and a create lot of services through reflection looping through mappings. I might lose the interface and just create the instance, without registering it at all. You can create it as an answer and I'll accept it in case nothing better shows up.

Comment: done. sometimes the simplest solution is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only registering IEntityDtoMappingProvider so that you use it to build your mapping component then maybe you shouldn't register it. This sort of one time configuration is often best done outside the scope of the container itself. As you suggested you can probably just remove the interface entirely and use the concrete class directly.

Same goes for things like logger configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a service factory which accepts the service provider instance and uses that to resolve other services. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEntityDtoMappingProvider), typeof(EntityDtoMappingProvider));
    
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var mappingService = sp.GetRequiredService<IEntityDtoMappingProvider>();
        var mappings = mappingService.GetEntityDtoMapping(typeof(Workflow).Assembly);

        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new EntitiesToDtosProfile(mappings));
        });
        
        return mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    });
    // ...
}
```

You would need to modify your `AddDatabaseGenericRepositories` and `AddMappingHelpers` methods to do something similar.

Comment: Your answer only works for a single service registration (in your case a singleton).

The methods AddDatabaseGenericRepositories and AddMappingHelpers add multiple services looping through the mappings and creating generic types like:
"var interfaceType = typeof(IMappingHelper<,>).MakeGenericType(mapping.Key, mapping.Value)", "var implementationType = typeof(MappingHelper<,>).MakeGenericType(mapping.Key, mapping.Value))" and afterwards registering all of them one by one like "services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, implementationType);" (or AddTransient, and so on).

Comment: In that case, I suspect you'll need to follow satnhak's advice, and create the `EntityDtoMappingProvider` instance manually rather than registering it in the DI container.